# Kissing Number: Proof in three dimension

Tags: geometry, number-theory

I am reading the proof to Kissing Number in three dimension given by https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0410324.pdf.

There is one part of the proof I don't really understand. So the proof mentions that $n^2 \le S(x) \lt 13n$, from here, the author directly mentions that we will have n < 13 and k(3) $\ge$ 12 directly. But how is this so? Can someone explain a little bit to me so that I can have a better understanding?

Sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, if $n^2<13n$, we must have $n<13$. If $n$ is an integer, this implies $n\leq 12$. On the other hand, in the introduction the authors mention that a configuration using $12$ balls exists, i.e. place $12$ balls at "positions corresponding to the vertices of a regular icosahedron concentric with the central ball." Since such a configuration exits and we are looking for the highest number of such balls, we must have $k(3) \geq 12$. Since by definition $n=k(3)$, then $n\leq 12, n\geq 12$ imply $n=12$.